# Is it possible to access Django application running on my local host to be accessible by another computer on other networks?

Tags: django

I am developing a web application on my local computer in Django.

Now I want my webapp to be accessible to other computers on other networks.

Comment: What do you mean by "other networks"? Do you want to show your Django application to your to customers? Or do you want to host it for production? In the context of showing web app to customers you can use Ngrok, it does not need any production configurations as Heroku do!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Heroku platform :)

https://www.heroku.com/

It's free and easily can deploy Django projects with Gunicorn. Corey also has a good video on how to do the process. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6DI_7Zja8Zc

Localhost is only for local, if you want to share between other computers on the same network then bind your django server to a static IP address but for other networks I think this would require something such as Heroku.

Comment: Its a bit disingenuous to say its free when no details on the application have been shared, i.e if any celery tasks are needed, redis caches, and other things that may cost. This also wouldn't be running on localhost and will not be a viable solution if an internet connection is not available

Comment: Then we would need better information from the publisher to help us better shape our answers...

Answer (score 0):

if you have static public IP address of your computer, without NAT or proxies, you can configure your webserver to handle http requests by your app.

Than you can access your web-app from other computers using your IP.

But I think **Shane Muirhead** told you better solution. [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) is a real shortest way to start deploying your webapp!